# Problems with promise retrieving data AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Looping through an array in my controller using angularjs and angularfire:

```
angular.forEach($scope.precourse, function(value, key){
   console.log(value);
});
```

Results in:

```
Object {$id: "-JUxrRDDip9wCwEx1t6j", $bind: function, $add: function, $save: function, $set: function…}

Object {$id: "-JUxrRDHo6Ph5_5_yUNF", $bind: function, $add: function, $save: function, $set: function…}

Object {$id: "-JUxrRDIGdTuhZkQQ73a", $bind: function, $add: function, $save: function, $set: function…}
```

Open one object I can see the different properties:

```
Object {$id: "-JUxrRDIGdTuhZkQQ73a", $bind: function, $add: function, $save: function, 
$set: function…}
$$hashKey: "00P"
$add: function (item) {
$auth: function (token) {
$bind: function (scope, name, defaultFn) {
$child: function (key) {
$getIndex: function () {
$getRef: function () {
$id: "-JUxrRDIGdTuhZkQQ73a"
$off: function (type, callback) {
$on: function (type, callback) {
$remove: function (key) {
$save: function (key) {
$set: function (newValue) {
$transaction: function (updateFn, applyLocally) {
$update: function (newValue) {
pairs: Object         //The Objects I'm intrested in
responsible: Object   //The Objects I'm intrested in
__proto__: Object
```

so let's print them out!

```
console.log(value.pairs);
console.log(value.responsible);
```

Result

```
undefined schedule.js:38
-JUrw5QLvIaBaICuKdmC schedule.js:39
undefined schedule.js:38
-JUsWS58wX4Y_zEf7FqG schedule.js:39
undefined schedule.js:38
-JU_6xy9_JDkgrE1mPSb
```

And if I use the $child() property

```
console.log(value.$child('pairs'));
console.log(value.$child('responsible'));

Object {$id: "pairs", $bind: function, $add: function, $save: function, $set: function…}
Object {$id: "responsible", $bind: function, $add: function, $save: function, $set: function…}
Object {$id: "pairs", $bind: function, $add: function, $save: function, $set: function…}
Object {$id: "responsible", $bind: function, $add: function, $save: function, $set: function…}
Object {$id: "pairs", $bind: function, $add: function, $save: function, $set: function…}
Object {$id: "responsible", $bind: function, $add: function, $save: function, $set: function…}
```

Why is this? I'm just looking for the actual values of the object, how do I get them? I want to use value.pairs to retrieve pairs but that won't work.

---

**EDIT:**
Added $on('loaded', function())

Code now looks:

```
angular.forEach($scope.precourses, function(value, key){
            value.$on('loaded', function(loadedValue) {
                console.log(loadedValue);
                console.log(loadedValue.pair);
            });
        });
```

Gives output:

```
Object {responsible: "-JU_6xy9_JDkgrE1mPSb"} schedule.js:40
undefined schedule.js:41
Object {responsible: "-JUrw5QLvIaBaICuKdmC"} schedule.js:40
undefined schedule.js:41
Object {responsible: "-JUsYm9UtONz0NzNTqbT"} schedule.js:40
undefined schedule.js:41
```

Press button to repeat forEach-loop again:

```
(after short delay)
Object {pairs: Object, responsible: "-JU_6xy9_JDkgrE1mPSb"} schedule.js:40
Object {-JUYhpPWOXqSpDNph5lo: "-JUYhpPWOXqSpDNph5lo", -JU_6xy9_JDkgrE1mPSb: "-JU_6xy9_JDkgrE1mPSb", -JUrw5QLvIaBaICuKdmC: "-JUrw5QLvIaBaICuKdmC"} schedule.js:41
Object {pairs: Object, responsible: "-JUsWS58wX4Y_zEf7FqG"} schedule.js:40
Object {-JUsWEf-v5XxIcLJSFgz: "-JUsWEf-v5XxIcLJSFgz", -JUsWS58wX4Y_zEf7FqG: "-JUsWS58wX4Y_zEf7FqG", -JUsYm9UtONz0NzNTqbT: "-JUsYm9UtONz0NzNTqbT"} schedule.js:41
Object {pairs: Object, responsible: "-JUrvf-rxHZPc4kF-IBb"} schedule.js:40
Object {-JUZSc-QEO0U0rf7hLV4: "-JUZSc-QEO0U0rf7hLV4", -JUdf8Z-uxlc0_sg-ZzB: "-JUdf8Z-uxlc0_sg-ZzB", -JUrvf-rxHZPc4kF-IBb: "-JUrvf-rxHZPc4kF-IBb"} schedule.js:41
```

**EDIT #2**
Ok I think I found the problem. It's in the service file where the schedule is created:

Inside /service/schedule.js

```
angular.forEach(preCourse, function (value, key){
        scheds.$child(schedId).$child('courses').$child('precourses').$add({
          responsible: value
        }).then(function (ref) {
          console.log('Inside Precourse');
scheds.$child(schedId).$child('courses').$child('precourses').$child(ref.name()).$child('pairs').$child(mainCourse[key]).$set(mainCourse[key]);
              scheds.$child(schedId).$child('courses').$child('precourses').$child(ref.name()).$child('pairs').$child(afterCourse[key]).$set(afterCourse[key]);
        });
      });
```

In my Controller I now create a schedule and log result of precourse:

```
$scope.schedule = Schedule.scheduleEvent($scope.eve);
$scope.schedule.$on('loaded', function() {
            $scope.precourses = $scope.schedule.courses.precourses;
            console.log($scope.precourses);     
                });
```

Which results in:

```
Object {-JUyS4KEV3ljmNvmb8kL: Object, -JUyS4KHH9dM5qwhr_uX: Object, JUyS4KJOjjh5DGu3LSk: Object}
-JUyS4KEV3ljmNvmb8kL: Object
    responsible: "-JUsWS58wX4Y_zEf7FqG"
    __proto__: Object
-JUyS4KHH9dM5qwhr_uX: Object
-JUyS4KJOjjh5DGu3LSk: Object
__proto__: Object

Inside Precourse
```

Any idea of what's wrong with my promises? Possible conflict between .then (service) and $on('loaded') (controller)

Comment: $on has been removed in AngularFire 0.8. I'd recommend upgrading and using the new $asObject and $asArray functions. Calling $asObject will return a $FirebaseObject and you can iterate through it's properties.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably logging `console.log(value.pairs);` before the data loads from firebase. If you upgrade to v0.8 then you can use `$loaded()` to wait for the data to load. With the version you are currently using you can use `$on("loaded")`

e.g.

```
value.$on("loaded", function(loadedValue) {
    console.log(loadedValue.pairs);
}
```

Comment: that is a splendid answer, Thanks! To get this to work 100% correct though, I need to repeat the forEach-loop at least twice (by button press) to get anything other than 'undefined' in my console. Guess the loading problem is the error here as well. Is there anyway to just pause everything to make sure that everything is loaded properly? such as 'TimeOut(500)'

Comment: are you using `$on` and still getting undefined? if so are you logging out `value` instead of `loadedValue`? Even when the loaded function gets called `value` will still not be initialized so you have to use the parameter that gets passed into the function

Comment: updated the question (below Edit) with my new code. Looks super after second iteration.

Comment: hmmm. I don't know why it's not loaded on the first run. Maybe try value.$child('pairs').$on('loaded', ...)

Comment: Same result I'm afraid. It can't be that I have to use $on.('loaded') on $scope.precourse in some way?

Comment: Updated description once more. Seems like there's some problems with my promises and $on('loaded') which means that angularfire thinks the objects are ready even if they aren't